# Project x was not imported due to file not existing (path length issue)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-restore

I am currently facing the error (see screenshot) where I can not add dependencies anymore on my Visual Studio solution. Would this have to do with path issues, or is something else going on.

I already tried nuget restore, cleaning the solution etc...

The reason the filenames are so long is because of clarity where they belong to, but if this is a limitation (which I expect, but can't find it) then how do I best go to work?

[image: Error in VS2019]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS also has a MAX_PATH limitation. This limitation is 260 characters. Even if your file path is below this character limit, you may experience issues due to reserved space. [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d614d0ba-eea2-444b-9be8-7fe4fb85a226/problem-re-path-length-allowed-for-new-project-in-vs2005?forum=csharpide)

I recommend creating a simple and short hierarchy and naming. You will have a lot of trouble naming this way.

If you want to continue naming this, make the following settings in your operating system and reopen and test your project:

First,

- open the registry with **regedit**
- Double click **LongPathsEnabled** in
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`. If
  this item is missing, create a new one. Set **Value Data to 1** and save

Second, (if In Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise)

- Run **gpedit.msc** in the Start menu
- Find "**Enable Win32 long paths**" under "`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem`" and double click to open it
- Mark as **Enabled** and save

Restart the computer.

Once your computer restarts and you open your project, the problem should be resolved.

If there is still a yellow warning next to NuGet packages, confirm it by typing dotnet restore in Nuget Packet Manager. (Make sure you choose the default project correctly). Restart Visual Studio if needed.

Comment: thanks for the advice, although I understand your recommendation it's time to get rid of MAX_PATH for modern apps, jeez.. I hate it. I don't want to shorten project names as they don't reflect what is in there then... But of course that's out of our hands, or yours.